# CDF of max($X$, $Y$) - where is the mistake?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v.'s and we know $F_X(x)$ and $F_Y(y)$. Let $Z=max(X,Y)$. Find $F_Z(z)$.

Here's my reasoning:

$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(max(X,Y)\leq z)$.

I claim that we have 2 cases here:

1) $max(X,Y)=X$. If $X<z$, we are guaranteed that $Y<z$, so $F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(X<z)=F_X(z)$

2) $max(X,Y)=Y$. Similarly, $F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(Y<z)=F_Y(z)$

Since we're interested in either case #1 or #2,

$F_Z(z)=F_X(z)+F_Y(z)-F_X(z)*F_Y(z)$

However, it's wrong and I know it. But I would like to know where the flaw in my reasoning is. I ***know the answer*** to this problem, I just want to know at what moment my reasoning fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are fine with separating the cases, but then do not take care of them correctly. Since when you say in your case 1 that the maximum is $X$, you are "conditioning on" $X>Y$ and that changes the space over which you calculate the probabilities.

We have two cases that either of which happens:

case 1: $X<Y<z$

case 2: $Y<X<z$.

That is 
\begin{align}
\Pr(\max\{X,Y\}<z)&=\Pr(X<Y<z)+\Pr(Y<X<z)\\
&=\int_{x=-\infty}^z\int_{y=x}^zf_Y(y)f_X(x)dydx+\int_{y=-\infty}^z\int_{x=y}^zf_Y(y)f_X(x)dxdy\\
&=\int_{y=-\infty}^z\int_{x=-\infty}^yf_Y(y)f_X(x)dxdy+\int_{y=-\infty}^z\int_{x=y}^zf_Y(y)f_X(x)dxdy\\
&=\int_{y=-\infty}^zf_Y(y)\left(\int_{x=-\infty}^yf_X(x)dxdy+\int_{x=y}^zf_X(x)dx\right)dy\\
&=\int_{y=-\infty}^zf_Y(y)\left(\int_{x=-\infty}^zf_X(x)dxdy\right)dy\\
&=F_Y(z)F_X(z).
\end{align}

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the sets in the first line of the proof

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you please let me know where the mistake is?

Comment: After the $+$; it probably should be $\mathbb{P}(Y<X<z)$

Comment: also in the third line, how are we changing the integration bounds?

Comment: Since the functions are all positive we may change the order of integration - due to Tonelli

Comment: yeah but we also changed the range, from $y=x$ to $y=-\infty$

Comment: Sorry, im not trying to be annoying I'm genuinely interested. My exam in this subject is in a couple of weeks.

Comment: I just checked your comment about "after the $+$...", and you were of course right I had a typo which I corrected. The rest seems to be fine :-)

Comment: To change the order of integration I simply look at the space that I have to span graphically, then it becomes easy to see how to change the limits ...

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is nice to have more than one way of showing this.

Comment: @itry you are most welcome :-)

Comment: this accepted answer, although mathematically correct does not seem to address the original question "WHY is my reasoning incorrect" (besides: surviving typos in the nested integral differnetials)

Answer (score 3):

$\max(X,Y)\le z$ means that *both* $X$ and $Y$ are $\le z$.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning, of using the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, would be fine if you were dealing with minimum rather than maximum.

$\bullet \quad F_{\min \{X,Y\}}(z) ~{=~ \mathsf P(X\leq z~\cup~Y\leq z) \\=~ F_X(x)+F_Y(z)-F_X(z)\cdot F_Y(z)}\\\bullet\quad F_{\max\{X,Y\}}(z)~{=~\mathsf P(X\leq z~\cap~Y\leq z)\\=~F_X(z)\cdot F_Y(z)}$

Comment: Can you write the proof of this?

Comment: What do you not follow?  When the maximum of two random numbers is less than a constant value, then both of the r.v. are less than that value.  When the minimum of the two r.v. is less than a value then we only know that *at least one* from the two is less than the value.  The rest is just the principle of inclusion and exclusion, and the fact that these r.v. are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works until you write "either... or..." instead of "and".

In practice, your last formula is computing the probability that $X \le z$ or $Y \le z$ but not both. Hence, for $X \le z$, you implicitly compute the probability that $Y > z$; likewise, for $Y \le z$, you consider the probability that $X > z$.