# Is there a name for the probability distribution formed by taking the product of the cumulative probability distributions?

Tags: probability, terminology

Basically, the title.

Given two continuous, real, random variables $X, Y$, with CDFs $F_x, F_y$, is there a name for the random variable $Z$ with CDF $F_x \cdot F_y$?

Note that $Z = \max(X, Y)$.

Comment: You gave it yourself, it's the max. What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CDF of max($X$, $Y$) - where is the mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311848/cdf-of-maxx-y-where-is-the-mistake)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Okay. Then is there a name for the random variable $\max(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, where each $x_i$ is independently drawn from the standard normal distribution?